# Rails downloads PDF instead of displaying it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

In my Rails app I'm using Faraday to connect with 3rd party API. In one of the endpoint I'm downloading the pdf which means that the API will send me a binary file as a response. Now I want to display this pdf to the user, to make it work I've got below controller action:

```
def document
  file = client.document(params[:id])

  send_data(file, disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/pdf')
end
```

But instead of displaying the PDF, the download is started. What did I missed?

Comment: @KJ if so how to render that file in a new window instead downloading when the `document_path` is fired up ?

Comment: @KJ alright, I've checked that in firefox and that code works like a charm but it does not using Chrome. Is there any way to force the same behaviour for Chrome?

Comment: Lol, don't you think that would be bizarre to expect from the user to have set something like you expecting? Anyway, found it - all I need is to set `headers: { 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline' })` as a `send_file` params.

Comment: I am confused. Was the `disposition` option not designed to set the header ??

Comment: @Maxence it absolutely is [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/data_streaming.rb#L137) not sure what is going on here.

Comment: 2 years ago I saw that it was a Rails issue with some open PR here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues but I don't see it anymore. As you can see the problem still exists so not quite sure how it was fixed.

Comment: @mr_muscle you mean this [Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36277) looks like it is not so much a problem as it is a configuration you need to change. [See Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-content-types-allowed-inline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, maybe it will be helpful for someone in the future.

All I need was to set `Content-Disposition` headers like below:

```
def document
  file = client.document(params[:id])

  send_data(file, disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/pdf', headers: { 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline' })
end
```